# megaraid storage manager doesn't see localhost raid

Tags: linux, raid, hardware-raid, raid10, megaraid

we have linux red hat 6 on ibm server and we had raid 10 on it which we monitored with megaraid storagemanager and everything was fine.

but on 3 days ago we restarted server (poweroff, pressed button ) and after that we realised that megaraid storage manager no longer detects localhost raid.

it detects other raids on different servers in same network as localhost but it does not detect localhost raid. megaraid storage managers on the other server do not detect that particular raid too but they detect their and eachothers.

i doubt raid is damaged cause no orange light is blinking and production 24/7 server is working just fine. its is that raid is for some reason just not visible to megaraid controlers

so question is - is there some process or something which should be start for raid in order to make it visible for megaraid control managers?

i do not want to shutdown production server to make sure raid is fine and then start it up again and be unable to connect to it with megaraid manager again..